# Submit data to Google script and keep user on my site (validation conflict)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a form that submits data to a Google script. Currently my users are sent to Google's page when submitting a form. I tried adding an ajax script to keep them on the page after submitting but when I do that my validation script doesn't work. When I try to combine them neither script works. One of the issues is that the "post" url is decided using a php script (due to Google,s limitations) Below is my code, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**Submit information to Google and keep user on my page:**

```js
$('#agentForm').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $actionURLs[$counter]; ?>',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#agentForm').serialize(),
        complete:function(){
            //whatever you wanna do after the form is successfully submitted
    window.location = "agents.php?agentID=<?php echo $_GET['agentID']; ?>&email=<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>&action=submitted";
        }
    });
});
```

**Validation:**

```js
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
function validateForm()
{
 var pax = jQuery('input[name="passengers"]:checked').length > 0;
 var rph = jQuery('input[name="reservation"]:checked').length > 0;
 
 var validationPassed = true;
 var msg = '';
 //console.log(pax);
 //console.log(rph);
 //console.log(jQuery('#mco').val());
 //console.log(jQuery("input:radio[name='flights']").is(":checked"));
 //console.log(jQuery("input:radio[name='iscorrect']").is(":checked"));
 
 if(!pax){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='Please select at least one passenger.</br>';
 }
  
 if(!rph){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='Please select at least one segment.</br>';
 }
  
 if(jQuery('#mco').val() != '' && !jQuery.isNumeric(jQuery('#mco').val())){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='MCO Amount must be a numeric value.</br>';
 }
 
 if (!jQuery("input:radio[name='flights']").is(":checked")){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='Are all flights being flown?</br>';
 }
  
 if (!jQuery("input:radio[name='iscorrect']").is(":checked")){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='Is the total correct?</br>';
 }
 else if(jQuery('input[name=iscorrect]:checked').val() == 'INCORRECT' && jQuery('#correct_amount').val() == ''){
  validationPassed = false;
  msg +='Please specifiy the correct amount.</br>';
 }
 else if(jQuery('input[name=iscorrect]:checked').val() == 'INCORRECT' && jQuery('#correct_amount').val() != '' && !jQuery.isNumeric(jQuery('#correct_amount').val())){
  msg +='Correct amount must be a numeric value.</br>';
 }
 
 if(!validationPassed){ 
  jQuery('.errors').show();
  jQuery(window).scrollTop(jQuery('.errors').offset().top);
 }
 
 jQuery('.errors').html(msg);
 return validationPassed;
}

jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
 jQuery("input[name='iscorrect']").click(function(){
  jQuery('#correct_amount').val('');
  /*if(jQuery('input[name=iscorrect]:checked').val() == 'INCORRECT'){
   
   jQuery("#correct_amount").prop("readonly", false);
  }
  else{
   jQuery('#correct_amount').val('');
   jQuery("#correct_amount").prop("readonly", true);
  }*/
 });
 
 jQuery("input[name='correct_amount']").click(function(){
  jQuery('#INCORRECT').prop('checked', true);
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your validation is not working because you have stopped propagation of the event in your JavaScript first code with `e.preventDefault()`.
Try to call `validateForm()` directly inside your first submit event listener, like that:

```
$('#agentForm').submit(function(e){
    validateForm();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url:'<?php echo $actionURLs[$counter]; ?>',
        type:'post',
        data:$('#agentForm').serialize(),
        complete:function(){
            //whatever you wanna do after the form is successfully submitted
             window.location = "agents.php?agentID=<?php echo $_GET['agentID']; ?>&email=<?php echo $_GET['email']; ?>&action=submitted";
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It still isn't working. Now the error messages are showing it just isn't preventing the form from being submitted.